# How to change output file name/directory of Sweave/Knitr?

Tags: r, aws-lambda, r-markdown, knitr, sweave

I have been tasked with running R and Knitr on an AWS Lambda (serverless computing) but since the folder structure of a Lambda is different, I'm having some issue with it.

This is have what I have so far (Lambda automatically calls my_function):

```
library(knitr)
?knit

my_function <- function() {
    knit("./test.Rnw")
}
```

The error i'm getting is :

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Error in file(file, ifelse(append, \"a\", \"w\")): cannot open the connection\n",
  "errorType": "simpleError"
}
```

I'm almost certain it is related to how/where it is trying to output the file, I don't think there's anything wrong with the .Rnw file since it reaches 100% :

```
processing file: ./test.Rnw

  |                                                                       
  |                                                                 |   0%
  |                                                                       
  |.................................................................| 100%
   inline R code fragments
```

My question is, how can I change the output of Knitr, ideally also be able to check where it is trying to create the file? Or maybe just more info about the error.

Worth noting I'm a Python developer and have 0 knowledge of R/Knitr/Sweave/Latex/R-Markdown, all I'm trying it to get a Proof of Concept working.

Comment: I am not sure about this specific case, but it seems like this library tries to open the file in the `'w'` mode, while in the Lambda container the only writable file system partition is `/tmp`. Please try to copy your file there first and then open.

Comment: @NikolayGrischenko that was it! Please post as answer so I can mark it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library tries to open the file in the `'w'` mode, while in the Lambda container the only writable file system partition is `/tmp`. Please try to copy your file there first and then open.